# open firefox from chrome via achor tag?

Tags: html, google-chrome, firefox

We have a bunch of internal support users who are "impersonating" customers to help them with their technical problems.

However, we lose the internal support memebers session when we impersonate... Was hoping there was a way to make a link in chrome open in firefox, or vice versa on click....

I saw some older "shell" javascript solutions, but we have both Mac and Windows users, and most use chrome/firefox anyways..

is there a clean way to do this? I am hoping not to have to rewrite our impersonation functionality!

Comment: This is not possible, would be a huge security risk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From lack of response, I am assuming this is a bad route to go. Instead we will be using the

```
windows.create({"url": url, "incognito": true});
```

strategy of not affecting the users current session and cookies.